# No emulators available for cordova

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

For some reason I have no emulators available in cordova / ionic.

**Cordova:**

```
$ cordova run ios --list 
Available ios devices:
Available ios virtual devices:
```

**Ionic:**

```
$ ionic cordova emulate --list
> cordova run --list --emulator
Available ios virtual devices:
```

I don't understand why this is happening or how to install them.  When I open xcode, they are available, but they do not appear in the CLI.

Comment: If you go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations, do you have something on "Command Line Tools"?

Comment: @jcesarmobile yes, I see Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Answer (score 0):

Give this one a try:

`cd platforms/ios/cordova && npm install ios-sim@latest`

Comment: what about android?